# Spring configuration in multi-module project

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm new to Spring and got a situation that single project with multiple modules including one web module. Web module uses Spring MVC, but I was wondering if I can have main Spring configuration at project level that takes care of whole project, so that I can take full advantages of Spring framework.

```
main
   -module1
   -module2
   -web
      +spring3.1, spring-security
```

What would be the best setting for this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The build layout and runtime CLASSPATH are two different things. Even if you define separate `applicationContext.xml` files or `@Configuration` classes in different modules, they *might* get merged into a single CLASSPATH.

That being said `module1` and `module2` might declare their own contexts, but since the CLASSPATH is merged at runtime, only a single main context will be created. Also if you choose to use CLASSPATH scanning in one module, it might pick-up classes (beans) annotated with `@Service` in other modules.

In `web` module, which should also have dependencies on Spring core libraries, will also depend on `spring-web`, MVC and `spring-security`. This module will create child `web` context, that has access to main context but not the other way around.

Obviously you should have only a single copy of each library in your uber-JAR (`ear`?)

Answer (score 8):

We have this kind of architecture where I work. We decided to use the ContextLoaderListener (Spring Event Listener) in the web module.

Then, in the serverApplicationContext.xml, we import all the modules context files :

```
<import resource="classpath*:module1ApplicationContext.xml" />
<import resource="classpath*:module2ApplicationContext.xml" />
...
```

Thus you leverage the spring context loading during the web application context initialization.