# Maven, Spring configuration for multi-module project

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am looking to set up a multi module maven project (described below) that would scale well. I have some questions about the approach which is largely drawn from the [Sonatype example](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html).

I have done a certain amount of reading on maven multi module projects but couldn't find an example going beyond the basic level.

### Questions:

1. Is this (below) a good project structure to start with? Or does it smell of disaster right from the start - i.e. would lead to heavy restructuring when setting up builds? In short, I am looking to avoid setting up something that goes against the grain with Maven.
2. I am expecting some modules to be quite independent, while most will be interrelated. Is it alright to start with each module as a Git repo and later refactor in together modules that are tightly linked?

### Objectives:

1. Good project structure for a modular Spring, JSF2, Maven based project, that would allow for builds involving a selection of modules and their dependencies.
2. It should be possible to deploy an individual web module on a lightweight container like Tomcat/Jetty through Maven configuration (like jetty-maven-plugin). This should be able to pull in the necessary dependencies through Maven. That makes it easy during development to focus on the module being worked on (not having to run a full build and deployment) and deploy the full application only in a complete build.
3. The setup should allow for multiple distributions based on a selection of modules to be included in the build. I take it this can be achieved through the use of build modules that will pull and package the corresponding modules.

### Project structure

```
Core domain classes.  
somapp.core (maven project)  
 |- someapp.core (maven module)  
 |- someapp.core.tests  

Account Management Domain classes   
someapp.accountmgmt   
|- someapp.accountmgmt   
|- someapp.accountmgmt.tests   

component1 domain classes   
someapp.component1   
|- someapp.component1   
|- someapp.component1.tests

Service 1 - # account management (User login)
someapp.accountmgmt  
 |- someapp.accountmgmt.api  
 |- someapp.accountmgmt.impl  
 |- someapp.accountmgmt.mocks  
 |- someapp.accountmgmt.tests  

someapp.service2  
 |- someapp.service2.api  
 |- someapp.service2.impl  
 |- someapp.service2.mocks   
 |- someapp.service2.tests   
 |- someapp.service2.cli    # CLI access for service2

someapp.service3  
 |- like above  

someapp.accountmgmt.web  
 |- someapp.accountmgmt.web  

someapp.service2.web  
 |- someapp.service2.web  

someapp.service3.web  
 |- someapp.service3.web  

someapp.build1 # bundle accountmgmt and service2 into 1 war file  

someapp.build2 # bundle accountmgmt and service3 into 1 war file  

somapp.build3 # bundle  accountmgmt, service2 and service3 into 1 war file  

(i.e. someapp.accountmgmt.web.war, someapp.accountmgmt.jar, someapp.service2.web.war, someapp.service2.jar, someapp.service3.web.war, someapp.service3.jar, someapp.core.jar)
```

I understand project structures are not set in stone. I would like to set up one that is a good starting point. Suggestions / Links to examples are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Well for the Spring part it's already discussed and an answer accepted at [Spring Configuration in a multi-module project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8932724/spring-configuration-in-multi-module-project).  As far as the general layout I've only seen one WAR per project and services only bundled together if they are related (e.g. UserLoginService would not go together with DomainObjectsService).

I would suggest breaking up the structure into several different projects, with the dependencies (business objects, etc) deployed as JAR projects to a local repo and listed as normal Maven dependencies in the (now different) projects that need them.  Then in your app-server you can deploy the apps to different paths (e.g. yourdomain.com/app1, yourdomain.com/service2).

My compliments to your ambition though!

EDIT: There is a way to have multiple WARs if you wish, see this SpringSource blog post about [Using a shared parent application context in a multi-war Spring application](http://spring.io/blog/2007/06/11/using-a-shared-parent-application-context-in-a-multi-war-spring-application/).

Answer (score 0):

A hierarchy starting with Spring IO through to your artifacts can be done as a single build multi-module project.

```
Spring-IO (dependencies)
   - Your parent pom (custom and further dependency management, plugins etc)
      - someapp-parent (really just a container for each -independent- sub-module)
         someapp-api    (deploy as jar into Nexus
         someapp-remote (Implements API and makes REST calls to your web app - also an independent jar)
         someapp-web    ('war' Exposes REST - JSON - representations of your API domain objects)
         someapp-dashboar (Admin console working with the API/web app via remote so you can manage everything, also a 'war')
```

Spring IO is BTW really good as a blessed set of dependencies that work well together and avoid classloader issues.  Well worth migrating your project to use it as the latest version looks pretty up-to-date.  I'd also recommend using Spring Boot for your web app(s).

As outlined I think its worth having all your app-related modules build as one so versioning is easier and you can test everything in a single build command.  I've recently worked on a project where we keep all these modules separate, and it just means 4x the effort to merge changes, build artifacts, deploy artifacts etc.